# Are there any "YouTube-styled" commenting systems for WordPress?

Tags: comments

I'm looking for a commenting system that allows users to like/dislike each other's comments with the highest liked comments automatically rising to the top, much like YouTube's commenting system. Anybody know of something like this?

Answer (score 2):

[Disqus](http://disqus.com/) handles this use case.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [**Comment Rating**](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/comment-rating/) plugin which has that functionality